# How to show $\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x) \cosh(y) + i\cos(x) \sinh(y)$

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

How to show $$\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x) \cosh(y) + i\cos(x) \sinh(y)$$

I begin with $$\sin(x+iy) = \frac{e^{x+iy}-e^{-x-iy}}{2i} = \frac{e^xe^{iy}-e^{-x}e^{-iy}}{2i}$$

$$ = \frac{e^xe^{iy}-e^{-x}e^{iy}+-e^{-x}e^{iy}-e^{-x}e^{-iy}}{2i}$$

$$ = \frac{e^{iy}(e^x-e^{-x})-e^{-x}e^{iy}-e^{-x}e^{-iy}}{2i}$$

$$ = e^{iy}\sin(x) + \frac{-e^{-x}e^{iy}-e^{-x}e^{-iy}}{2i}$$

At this point I could have $\displaystyle\frac{-e^{-x}}{i}cos(iy)$ in the right term but I want to make $\cos(x)$ appear, so I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Why don't you develop $sin(a+b)$ as usual and later work $sin(iy)$ and $cos(iy)$ separately as you almost did ? This is just a suggestion.

Comment: I would try going in the reverse direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all $x,y\in \mathbb R$ the following holds:
$$\begin{align}
\sin(x+iy)&=\dfrac{e^{i(x+iy)}-e^{-i(x+iy)}}{2i}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{-y+ix}-e^{y-ix}}{2i}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{-y}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))-e^{y}(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))}{2i}\\
&=\dfrac{(e^{-y}-e^y)\cos(x)+i(e^{{-y}}+e^y)\sin(x)}{2i}\\
&=\dfrac{(e^{-y}-e^y)\cos(x)}{2i}+\dfrac{i(e^{{-y}}+e^y)\sin(x)}{2i}\\
&=i\sinh(y)\cos(x)+\cosh(y)\sin(x).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Nice. Just in the third line it should be $\sin(x)$ instead of $\sin(y)$.

Comment: @MattL. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I forgot the $i$ in the de Moivre's formula.

Comment: @dcholleton No problem.

Comment: I absolutely love the profile photo. Did you make it yourself?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Nope, found it on the web. I think mine is much smaller. [Here](https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3411/3647754686_95263f244d_z.jpg?zz=1)'s a larger version.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(x+iy)= \sin(x) \, \cos(iy) + \cos(x) \, \sin(iy) = \sin(x) \, \cosh(y) + i \, \cos(x) \,  \sinh(y).$$